# Windows XP support of Unicode

Tags: windows, unicode, windows-xp

I need to add the support of [some Unicode characters](http://www.duxburysystems.com/documentation/dbt11.1/miscellaneous/Special_Characters/Unicode_1dxx.htm) , i need especially the character
 ᵃ, i tried to solve the problem by adding the support of east asia languages but without a result.

These characters are supported in win 7 , but in windows XP are not.

Any help please .

Comment: Sure those glyphs are in the font your using on xp?

Comment: so i should check first if they are in the font i'm using in XP? , i have tried to view a web page containing those charachters in XP but it gives squares ?

Comment: In which sense do you need Windows XP support? Is this about programming, or just about using characters in some software? The character you mention is a modifier letter that has nothing to do with East Asian writing systems. It is possible that Windows XP system fonts lack this, but then the question is whether it is sufficient to install a suitable font in your computer – apparently not if this is about developing a program that should run on other people’s computers.

Comment: @HansPassant installing East Asia languages is the solution described in the web page above and it had'nt worked

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i wish to find the suitable font containing this character. in this case when i wanna use that font in another computer i have to just distrubute that font

Comment: Right.  It is U+1D43, you'll need to install a font that supports the "Phonetic Extensions" character set.  Should be hard to find since it is well supported on Win7.  Supporting a 10 year old operating system gets to be a lossy proposition.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah that should be another reason for a transition to Win 7, it seems that only solution is to work on Win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a large [number](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d43/fontsupport.htm) of fonts that contain phonetic characters like “ᵃ” U+1D43 MODIFIER LETTER SMALL A, and some of them are free, such as [DejaVu](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/) fonts, [Doulos SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=DoulosSILfont), and [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/). Normally a font needs to be installed on the user’s computer by the user, but if this is about a web or intranet page or an HTML5 application, you could also use `@font-face` to refer to the font, either online or as part of the application package.

Comment: Excellent :D , i will give a try